# Does anyone know why adding text into an element changes the width of the parent?

Tags: html, css

In the following example, I have div.center, within it I have a nav.

Without text inside the nav:

[Without Text inside nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shYHI.png)

However, the following occurs when I add text inside the nav:

[With Text inside nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J05mQ.png)

Can anyone explain why this occurs and how to overcome it?

Comment: can you share your code for better understanding? Images are not that helpful

Comment: Sure, it's in this repo: https://github.com/leanjunio/WEB222/tree/master/Assignments/A5

Comment: adding vertical-align: bottom to the 'nav' css. Will make it work fine

Answer (score 0):

Adding text to one of the three divs forces that div to be vertical aligned relative to the divs around it.  Once your other divs have content in them the issue will resolve itself.

You can fix this issue by adding `vertical-align: bottom;` to the `nav` css.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9075Luho/17/

However, your real issue stems from the fact that you're using inline-block for this layout. Flexbox might be a better approach for something like this. It looks like you're learning HMTL/CSS/JS for a class, and not sure what you've covered so far, but using flexbox for layouts like this is what is more common in real-life applications.